# Why doesn't the outside mass have any effect?

Tags: oscillators

In the classical oscillation problem, where a body is dropped through a tunnel that goes through the earth, an important part of the solution is that if the body is at distance $r$ from the centre of the earth, it is only affected by the mass of the earth which is within radius $r$. I cannot understand why the above mass has no effect on the body. I would like to hear an explanation.

Comment: This is by the [shell theorem](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/sifter/jennifer-lopez-set-produce-nbc-bio-terror-drama-crispr).

Comment: @knzhou  are you sure Jennifer Lopez contributed to this concept? That's the link I get....

Comment: @CountTo10 Wow, oops. Well, it could have been a lot worse.

Answer (score 1):

An individual mass in the outer shell ***does*** have an effect.

Bu if you consider ***all*** the individual infinitesimal masses in the outer shell, the total effect, the net overall force, is mathematically zero for any point inside the shell...

Comment: Incomplete without a specific mention of exact spherical symmetry.

Comment: And uniformity of density wrt angular variables.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This image is from [Wikipedia Shell Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem) but it might be more complicated than required for your question.

In general theoretical terms, no matter where you dig the hole,  not just directly down,  but through the Earth between say,  Washington and Miami, it should still take the same amount of time to fall, around 38 minutes, although you obviously will not oscillate unless you drop straight down. This assumes a realistic density profile, assuming a  constant density will take you around 42 minutes. It also assumes a spherically symmetrical gravitational field, as noted by Rob Jeffries above.

This is because, although there is less mass above you, (in the Washington to Miami dig), that upper mass  is much **closer** to you than the mass below you, which is much greater, but also much further away from you, so the gravitional effects balance out on each "side" of you.

If you keep digging at greater angles, until you reach  90 degrees straight down,  it should be easy to see how the gravitational effects balance out, with equal mass all around you.

From [Falling Through The Earth](http://science.howstuffworks.com/environmental/earth/geophysics/question3731.htm)

However, you may well be dead before your first oscillation.

> Due to the Coriolis effect and angular momentum, your sideways motion will carry you into a wall before you get terribly far down the shaft.
>
> To understand why, consider a hole drilled at the equator. Whether you stand on Earth's surface or near its core, you complete one revolution every 24 hours, but you don't travel the same distance: at the surface, you travel 24,900 miles (40,000 kilometers), while, halfway to the core, you journey half that distance. You would retain that 1,000 mph (1,600 kph) eastward motion as you fell, while the walls around you would move at an ever-slower eastward rate, causing you to run into them.
>
> To save yourself some rock rash, you could drill from pole to pole, where Coriolis has no effect. However, solar and lunar gravity, which also perturb orbiting satellites, would eventually pull you into the tunnel wall anyway